# Interleaved lifetime requirements for map/reduce

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker

I have basically the following code:

```rust
iter.map(|x| t.f(x))
    .reduce(|x, y| t.g(x, y))
    .unwrap_or_default()
```

where `f` and `g` both borrow mutably from `self`.

The Rust borrow checker is not amused by this idea. Apparently, I cannot construct two closures mutably borrowing the same data `t`. But theoretically, the mutable borrow in `f` and `g` are both temporary, which means if this code did compile, during execution their borrows should be interleaved in time, and thus should not cause any actual problem.

The lifetime problem can be resolved by inlining `f`, `g`, `map`, and `reduce` (after which the invocations of `f` and `g` are indeed interleaved in time, and the borrow checker is satisfied), but then the simplicity in program structure is totally ruined. Another way to solve this would be to wrap the mutably borrowed data by a `RefCell`, but I suspect it will introduce runtime penalty.

Is there any clever way to satisfy the borrow checker without compromising clarity?

---

I tried to partially inline `reduce` and `map`. The following does not type check (indeed it should not, since here `f` is repeatedly called on the first argument of `g`, while in the original code `f` is only invoked once on every item in `iter`):

```rust
iter.reduce(|x, y| t.g(t.f(x), t.f(y)))
    .unwrap_or_default()
```

Use a `fold` should solve this, see the following:

```rust
iter.fold(None, |res, y| Some(match res {
    None => t.f(y),
    Some(res) => t.g(res, t.f(y)),
})).unwrap_or_default()
```

But this code is inefficient (and not as readable): it will `match` on each iteration, while theoretically only one `match` is necessary.

If we use the trick in `reduce`, the code becomes tedious:

```rust
(|| {
    let first = iter.next()?;
    Some(iter.fold(t.f(first), |res, y| t.g(res, t.f(y))))
})().unwrap_or_default()
```

Another inconvenience is that `iter` is mentioned twice here, so I am forced to store this iterator in some variable, instead of directly use some expressions returning an iterator.

---

**Update:** MRE provided [here in Compiler Explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:45,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:45,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:45,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:45,startLineNumber:10),source:%27struct+A%3B%0Astruct+B%3B%0Astruct+Visitor%3B%0A%0Aimpl+Visitor+%7B%0A++++fn+visit_single(%26mut+self,+_:+A)+-%3E+B+%7B+todo!!()+%7D%0A++++fn+visit_two(%26mut+self,+_:+B,+_:+B)+-%3E+B+%7B+todo!!()+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+example(iter:+impl+Iterator%3CItem%3DA%3E,+mut+visitor:+Visitor)+-%3E+Option%3CB%3E+%7B%0A++++iter.map(%7Cx%7C+visitor.visit_single(x))%0A++++++++.reduce(%7Cx,+y%7C+visitor.visit_two(x,+y))%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.02194787379973,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1550,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-C+opt-level%3D2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27rustc+1.55.0+(Rust,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+rustc+1.55.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.978052126200275,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:1,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Well how about sacrificing clarity like this? `.reduce(|x, y| t.g(t.f(x), t.f(y)))`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I'm afraid the suggested code will not type check. Consider for example `f : A -> B` and `g : B -> B -> B`.

Comment: I would personally use a good old `for` loop here unless the `t` thing can be cleaned. Because I disagree the code is more readable this way. map/reduce constructs are clear as long as the process doesn't depend on the execution order, which is probably not the case if you have to mutably borrow something else. A casual reading would for example assume the calls to map all before the reduce.

Comment: @DenysSéguret The real situation is actually a visitor collecting information from an expression tree. `f` is a recursive call to visit the child subtree, and `g` is the actual reduce to produce a result for the current subtree. I don't see it inappropriate for a visitor to be mutably borrowed, since it collects information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `unwrap_or_default()` at the end, it means that a plain `.fold` can be a bit shorter

```
let result = v.iter()
    .fold(Default::default(), 
        |res, x| { let tfx = t.f(x); t.g(res, tfx) });
```

Unfortunately this even shorter version didn't work due to double borrow

```
let result = v.iter()
    .fold(Default::default(), 
        |res, x| t.g(res, t.f(x)));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=498d9366046e2eb98e3bf0075f481ccc)

Comment: In fact I have already considered this solution, but compared to the original code, this version call `t.g` n times, while the original code only call `t.g` (n - 1) times (with n being the number of items in the iterator). This is important because `t.g` has side-effects (and that is why it borrows mutably from `self`).

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

- we don't (yet?) have good solution to properly reuse `map` and `reduce`;
- `fold` with `Default::default()` is not semantically equivalent in that it call `t.g` once more than `map` followed by `reduce`;
- `fold` with `Option` is not as efficient;

My final solution is to factor out the `reduce_map` logic to a function:

```rust
pub trait IterHelper: Iterator {
    /// `Iterator::map` followed by `Iterator::reduce`, with lifetime issues properly handled.
    fn reduce_map<V, A>(mut self, visitor: &mut V,
                        f: impl Fn(&mut V, Self::Item) -> A,
                        g: impl Fn(&mut V, A, A) -> A) -> Option<A>
        where Self: Sized, V: ?Sized {
        let first = f(visitor, self.next()?);
        Some(self.fold(first, |res, x| {
            let a = f(visitor, x);
            g(visitor, res, a)
        }))
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> IterHelper for I {}
```